# error message tooltip not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I want to get error message using tooltip, I display:none in span with an id of demo to hide tooltip. Then get the id using getElementById javascript for username with an id of userverify to get if input is empty and then if value is empty then display block and innerhtml the id of demo

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userverify").value;
  var y;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    y = document.getElementById("demo").styleDisplay = "block";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y + "<h1>Empty Username</h1>";

  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="" name="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Username</label>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <input id="userverify" class="" type="text" name="username">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="demo" style="display:none">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
  <input onclick="validateForm()" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to close brackets in `y = document.getElementById("demo".styleDisplay = "block");`

Comment: im new sir do i need to add var y and innerhtml of "empty"?

Comment: please somebody help me i display none you cant see the tooltip in span with an id of demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
y = document.getElementById("demo").styleDisplay = "block";
```

is not correct...try `style.display`

Second your tooltip has `visibility:hidden` and `opacity:0` too....so you will need to change these values also with `display`.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userverify").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  //console.log(x);
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    y.style.display = "block";
    y.style.visibility = "visible";
    y.style.opacity = "1";
    y.innerHTML = "Empty Username";

  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="" name="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Username</label>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <input id="userverify" class="" type="text" name="username">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="demo" style="display:none">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
  <input onclick="validateForm()" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I did some changes to it. `validateForm()` function should not goes on the `submit` button but on the `form` element's `onSubmit` event. `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` this means that the submission will depend on the return value of the `validateFrom()` function.

```js
function validateForm(){

        var x = document.getElementById("userverify").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("demo");
        if(x == "" || x == null){
       y.style.display = "block";
       y.innerHTML = "Empty Username";    
       y.style.visibility = "visible";
       y.style.opacity = "1";
       return false;
        }
        else
        {
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
        
        return true;
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}


.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;

   
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="" name="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
   <label>Username</label>  
     <div class="tooltip">
         <input id="userverify" class="" type="text" name="username"> 
          <span class="tooltiptext" id="demo" style="display:none;">Tooltip text</span>
     </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                        
                        </form>
```

Comment: thanks sir i thought styleDisplay will display forever